# How to remove a specific character before and after a pattern match in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I want to remove `"#"` after a specific pattern match.

Ex:

in below code i will `grep` for `"SOME DESC"`. i want all the lines commented above and below `"SOME DESC"` to get Un-commented.

### existing code

```
#define service {
#        hostgroup_name          hmaster_hosts 
#        use                     local-service
#        servicegroups           SOME_GROUP
#        service_description     SOME DESC : service Service 
#        check_command           check_nrpe!check_something
#}
```

### After removal of "#"

```
define service {
    hostgroup_name          hmaster_hosts 
    use                     local-service
    servicegroups           SOME_GROUP
    service_description     SOME DESC : service Service 
    check_command           check_nrpe!check_something
}
```

i tried the below code to do the changes.

```
sed -i 's/#define service {/define service {/g' services.cfg
sed -i 's/#        hostgroup_name          /         hostgroup_name          /' services.cfg
sed -i 's/#        use                     /         use                     /' services.cfg
sed -i 's/#       servicegroups/       servicegroups/' services.cfg
sed -i 's/#        service_description     /         service_description     /' services.cfg
sed -i 's/#        check_command           /         check_command           /' services.cfg 
sed -i 's/#}/}/g' services.cfg
```

but the place of `#` is uncertain in the code i.e it can be  `#        hostgroup_name`or  `#hostgroup_name`or `#  hostgroup_name` so my approach dint worked for some part of the code. i wanted to know is there any better way to do this irrespective of the position of `#`

Comment: Tke a look at the `awk` utility. Start by reading it's manual page: `man awk`

Comment: how many lines above and below? It isn't clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you have *GNU* `awk`, you can try the following:

```
awk -v search='SOME DESC' -v RS='(^|\n)#define service \\{[^}]*\\#\\}\n' '
  index(RT, search) { RT = gensub("(^|\n)#", "\\1", "g", RT) }
  { printf "%s%s", $0, RT }
' file
```

<sup>The above assumes that the commented lines start directly with `#` and that the code follows directly after, as in the sample input in the question. For a variant solution that works with variable amounts of whitespace, see bottom.</sup>

This assumes that commented lines of interest are *blocks* of commented `define service { ... }` lines that should be uncommented as a whole if the search string is found inside the block.

- `-v search='SOME DESC'` pass the literal string to search for as Awk variable `search`.
- `-v RS='(^|\n)#define service \\{[^}]*\\#\\}\n'` defines `RS`, the input-record *separator*, as a regular expression that starts with a commented-out `define service {` line and and ends with a commented-out `}` line, followed by a newline.

  - This means that the data reported in `$0` for the current record comprises the line(s) *before* each block of interest.
  - However, GNU exposes the actual record terminator (separator) that the regex in `RS` matched via (nonstandard) variable `RT`. Thus, it is the value of `RT` that contains a block of interest in each iteration.
- `index(RT, search)` returns the 1-based index of the search string's position inside the block at hand, or 0, if the block doesn't contain the search string. When used as a pattern (a Boolean condition), the associated *action* (`{...}`) is therefore only executed if the block contains the search string.

  - `RT = gensub("(^|\n)#", "\\1", "g", RT)` removes the comment char. (`#`) from the very beginning of all lines in the block.
    Note that `gensub()` is a GNU-specific function that notably allows the use of references to capture groups (`\1` refers to what capture group `(^|\n)` matched; the extra `\` is needed, because `awk`'s *string* parsing process `\`-prefixed escape sequences too).
- `{ printf "%s%s", $0, RT }` prints the current record (`$0`) followed by the - potentially uncommented - block.

---

**Variant that works with variable amounts of whitespace**:

```
awk -v search='SOME DESC' -v RS='(^|\n)[[:blank:]]*#[[:blank:]]*define[[:blank:]]+service[[:blank:]]+\\{[^}]*\\#[[:blank:]]*\\}\n' '
  index(RT, search) { RT = gensub("(^|\n)[[:blank:]]*#", "\\1", "g", RT) }
  { printf "%s%s", $0, RT }
' file
```

This is essentially the same solution as above, except that (potentially empty) runs of spaces/tabs before and after the `#` are matched (`[[:blank:]]*`), and nonempty runs of variable length between the tokens of the `define` line (`[[:blank:]]+`).